# Center float column on last page in twocolumn mode

Tags: floats, koma-script, two-column

My two-column document ends with a page that has a single column containing a single float:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{figure}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{1.5\columnwidth}
        \caption{I want to be centered.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks odd. Is it possible to have this one centered on the page? At best, some automatic solution, but if automatism is not possible, that's also okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the starred environment `figure*` and `\centering` inside this environment:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \rule{\columnwidth}{1.5\columnwidth}
  \caption{I want to be centered.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]